# Can't change UIView attributes in the parent class / viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, class, model-view-controller, parent-child

I've been working with Swift for a few months, but my main viewcontroller files is going too big.

Is there any way to split this files to many subclasses?

Ex: 1 file to handle constraints.
1 file to handle user behaviours.
1 file to handle buttons...

I've tried to do it but didn't success to connect and communicate these files with each other.
Here is sample code:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
 var btn = UIButton();
 func DoTask() {
    // call child class to do task ChildTask()
    Child.ChildTask()
 }
}
class Child: KeyboardViewController {
 func ChildTask() {
   self.btn.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
 }
}
```

In this example, child class can't change UIButton (from parent class) attributes.
Anyway to do it?

Comment: read about [MVVM](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2015/09/24/mvvm-in-swift/). It should help

Comment: @R.K. can you give me an example code about it? particulally in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a good overview of some strategies you can adopt to make your view controllers in an [Objc.io article by Chris Eidhof](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/lighter-view-controllers/).

More concretely to your case, you can tend to have a view controllers hierarchy, where you have a parent view controller and child view controllers.

In order for them to communicate, the best approach in my opinion is:

1 - have the parent controller own a "model" class; this class models your UI properties (is a button highlighted? what is a text field content? etc.)

2 - when you create a child controller from the parent, pass it the shared model.

3 - use KVO ([tutorial here](http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/)) to make sure your UI react to your model changes.

In code, it would look like this (Swift 2.0):

```
private var myContext = 0

class MyModel : NSObject {

  dynamic var buttonTitle : String = "default title"
}

class MyChildVC : UIViewController {

  let model : MyModel
  @IBOutlet var button : UIButton?

  init(m : MyModel) {
    model = m
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.model.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "buttonTitle", options: .New, context: &myContext)

  }

  deinit {
    self.model.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "buttonTitle", context: &myContext)
  }

  override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?,
    ofObject object: AnyObject?,
    change: [String : AnyObject]?,
    context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

        if (keyPath == "buttonTitle") {
            button?.titleLabel?.text = self.model.buttonTitle
        }
  }

}


class MyParentVC : UIViewController {

  let model = MyModel()
  let vc1 : MyChildVC

  init() {
    self.vc1 = MyChildVC(m: model)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

  }

  func someOp() {

    self.model.buttonTitle = "NewTitle"
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

It may look daunting at first, but it works like a charm once you get used to it (and to KVO idiosyncrasies).

If you go for the view controllers hierarchy, do not forget to read a bit about [view controllers containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/).

Comment: I'm very appreciate for your answer. I'm taking a look on it. Today, i have a new solution.  What if i create an instance of viewcontroller which stays outside of the parent class like this `var kvc: KeyboardViewController!` . Inside the parent class, at `viewDidLoad` function, i assign `kvc = self` , so in any classes, i can easily access to the parent view controller by this instance of it? Is it a good solution ?

Comment: well, it is an alternative approach. You should make sure you tell the child controller which is its parent controller, either through an `init` parameter or by assigning a property...